# why my code isn't working while making fibonacci sequence inside a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, fibonacci

so i want to make a fibonacci sequence inside a list (not array), so i want the result to be something like this with the bracket symbols

[2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89]

i've made the code, please help me to spot the mistake

```
print('============FIBONACCI SEQUENCE PROGRAM===============')

number_of_sequence = int(input('Type the number of sequence = '))

first_value = int(input('Insert the first value = '))

second_value = int(input('Insert the second value = '))

first_sequence = ([2, 3])

sequence = first_sequence + ([0] * number_of_sequence)

for i in range (1, number_of_sequence-1) :

    sequence[i+1] = first_value + second_value

    first_value = second_value

    second_value = sequence

    print(sequence, end = ' ')
```

here's the output i got  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnOFQ.png)

Comment: A python list is equivalent to an array in most programming languages, what do you mean by "list (not array)"?

Comment: Other notes: Convert your image to text.  You always use 2,3 (ignoring first_ and second_value).  And of course the actual bug, `second_value = sequence`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure as to what you are doing, however, I fixed the error:

```
print('============FIBONACCI SEQUENCE PROGRAM===============')
number_of_sequence = int(input('Type the number of sequence = '))
first_value = int(input('Insert the first value = '))
second_value = int(input('Insert the second value = '))
first_sequence = ([2, 3])
sequence = first_sequence + ([0] * number_of_sequence)
for i in range(1, number_of_sequence-1):
    sequence[i+1] = first_value + second_value
    first_value = second_value
    second_value = sequence[i+1]
    print(sequence, end=' ')
```

The error was when you:

```
second_value = sequence
```

instead of:

```
second_value = sequence[i+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have some mistakes.
First of all, you asked the user to type the first and second values, but you didn't use them for the array.
And instead of using a new array, you can use the function `sequence.append()` that adds an element to the list.
Lastly, you set the variable second_value to be the sequence, which is a list, and then on the next iteration of the loop, you do `first_value + second_value`, which means that you try to add and int and a list, so that is where your error is coming from.
I recommend you to learn more about how to read errors.
I fixed your code, this is how it looks:

```py
number_of_sequence = int(input("Type the number of sequence = "))
first_value = 2
second_value = 3
sequence = [first_value, second_value]

for i in range(1, number_of_sequence-1):
    sequence.append(first_value + second_value)
    first_value = second_value
    second_value = sequence[-1]
print(sequence)
```

Comment: They aren't trying to append he is trying to replace a preset value of 0 in the list named `sequence`.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is caused by your assignment of the whole list to the second_value variable.  On the next iteration, when you try to add first_value and second_value, one is an integer and the other has become a list (which are incompatible and certainly not what you intended)

Also, you need to initialize your list with the two values that you got from the user (instead of starting it with 2 and 3).

After that, you can let Pyhton handle most of the work by using the list itself as the holder of previous values:

```
print('============FIBONACCI SEQUENCE PROGRAM===============')

number_of_sequence = int(input('Type the number of sequence = '))

first_value = int(input('Insert the first value = '))

second_value = int(input('Insert the second value = '))

sequence = [first_value, second_value] # start with user specified values

while len(sequence) < number_of_sequence:  # progressively fill the list
      sequence.append(sum(sequence[-2:]))  # appending sum of last two items

print(sequence) # print the sequence list only at end of loop
```

*Note, if it was really your intention to have two extra zeroes at the end of the sequence, you can add them after the loop*